# Getting error in Azure search ""Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"

Tags: content-search, azure-search

We are getting result thorough `content api` using Azure search and solr. In Solr, everything is working fine but when we are trying to get result in Azure search then we are getting the below error

[image]

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using? I found this possibly related post: https://horizontal.blog/2019/04/17/sitecore-content-search-with-azure-index-out-of-range-exception/

Comment: I am using Sitecore 9.1.1 version.